# mdadm Software RAID1 with GPT on Debian 8.0 amd64 - Does not boot on disk removal

Tags: linux, debian, boot, raid1, gpt

**INTRO:**

I have spent countless days attaching/detaching MOLEX->SATA power cables, rebooting machines and trying hundreds of edits and commands. I am on the verge of desperation and desperately in need of assistance.

---

**PROBLEME:**

As described in the title. I am a newbie, I followed [mdadm RAID1+GPT installation guide](http://kudzia.eu/b/2013/04/installation-of-debian-wheezy-on-mdadm-raid1-gpt/). My partitioning setup is exactly as in the guide, with the exception of an additional HDD. It installed, synced the arrays and pretended to be "all dandy". However when I powered off the machine, unplugged one of the drives and attempted to boot it failed with the message:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
  - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/long-UUID-here does not exist.
Dropping to a shell!
modprobe: module ehci-orion not found in modules.dep

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Debian 1:1.22.0-9+deb8u1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

/bin/sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
(initramfs)
```

Where */dev/disk-by-uuid/**long-UUID-here*** actually shows the UUID of the **md0**(RAID1 device 0 partition 1, used for root filesystem; as in guide)

Using `cat /proc/mdstat` and `mdadm --detail /dev/md0` from that "(initramfs) emergency shell thingy" it shows that the RAID arrays **md0** and **md1** are **inactive** , **marked as RAID0** and **each RAID member has an [S] after it** (likely indicating that it's a spare disk)

If I re-connect the detached HDDs it boots fine and pretends to be "clean". Showing all correct information as RAID1.

---

**I will be happy to get you more specific information/command outputs if you ask. This thing is driving me crazy.**

---

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION(full raid/all disks attached):**

*cat /proc/mdstat*

```
Personalities : [raid1]
md0 : active raid1 sdc3[1] sdb3[0] sdd3[2]
      1945569280 blocks super 1.2 [3/3]  [UUU]
      bitmap: 0/15 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdc2[1] sdb2[0] sdd2[2]
      7808000 blocks super 1.2 [3/3]  [UUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

*mdadm --detail /dev/md0*

```
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Sun Apr 26 22:20:03 2015
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 1945569280 (1855.44 GiB 1992.26 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1945569280 (1855.44 GiB 1992.26 GB)
   Raid Devices : 3
  Total Devices : 3
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Tue Apr 28 01:32:45 2015
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : FluffyBunny:0  (local to host FluffyBunny)
           UUID : 9c0b29dd:ea96cffe:9431dc07:4bd35b5e
         Events : 4408

Number    Major    Minor    RaidDevice  State
  0         8       19           0      active sync  /dev/sdb3
  1         8       35           1      active sync  /dev/sdc3
  2         8       51           2      active sync  /dev/sdd3
```

*fdisk -l*

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A5E04E17-28EA-4205-96C4-40B0064241B9

Device        Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1      2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdc2      4096   15628287   15624192  7.5G Linux RAID
/dev/sdc3  15628288 3907028991 3891400704  1.8T Linux RAID

Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7232955A-62E8-4251-AF2F-B3EC70164234

Device        Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb2      4096   15628287   15624192  7.5G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb3  15628288 3907028991 3891400704  1.8T Linux RAID

Disk /dev/sdd: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 04C652AA-FC29-45D1-B866-CCEDAE4164D7

Device        Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1      2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdd2      4096   15628287   15624192  7.5G Linux RAID
/dev/sdd3  15628288 3907028991 3891400704  1.8T Linux RAID

Disk /dev/md1: 7.5 GiB, 7995392000 bytes, 15616000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/md0: 1.8 TiB, 1992262942720 bytes, 3891138560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Comment: I have never tried it, but I wonder if you could set the force the root device to be `/dev/md0` or whatever by editing your `grub.cfg`. If that did work you would have to do some tweaking to fix it so that the scripts that generate the `grub.cfg` create the right options.

Comment: @Zoredache Please keep in mind that I am a newbie. I not not know how to do that. I am assuming you meant the file located at "[/boot/grub/grub.cfg](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.config-bootloader.html#sect.config-grub)" though.

Comment: @Zoredache Also please note that I mentioned that UUID that it searches for is actualy the UUID of the /dev/md0

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Grub2 on *both* disks. Try to run `grub2-install /dev/sda; grub2-install /dev/sdb` (or similar; check you grub man page for more information).

EDIT: after reading better your post, I think Grub2 is not the culprit here, as it seems that your system correctly load the required kernel. Try to substitute the UUID with the /dev/ entry pointing to your mdadm device (eg: /dev/md0). It changes something?

Comment: If you look at the very bottom of that guide (in the link I provided) it includes "root@debian:~# grub-install /dev/sdb". As such, I have carried out that exact operation on all 3 RAID members.

Comment: I have also tried editing the /etc/fstab to replace UUID with /dev/mdX. It outputs exactly identical error result.

Comment: Ah, I just edited my reply. Sorry for the noise. Unfortunately, I did have no clue about this problem.